# MongoDB Java - $push to List<DBRef> is overwriting existing entries

Tags: java, mongodb, set, push, dbref

MongoDB Java - List update is causing existing entries to be overwritten.

I have setup a 3 node mongo 4.0.27 replica set with 1 primary and 2 secondary nodes.

I am executing a Push operation on a List to add new entries. However this is resulting in an overwrite of previous entries as the $push seems to be getting converted into $set. in the oplog.

I am trying to insert 20 new entries into the list.

Can see the following in the driver DEBUG logs.

```
*2022-08-30 13:11:42 [http-nio-8080-exec-45] DEBUG 
org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command -Sending command '{"update": "orgEntity", 
"ordered": true, "writeConcern": {"w": 3, "j": true}, "txnNumber": 59, "$db": 
"productDB", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1661845302, "i": 
29}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", 
"subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 0}}, "lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": 
"qAABBCCDDEEFFSSAAEE/AAD7A==", "subType": "04"}}}, "updates": [{"q": {"_id": {"$oid": 
"63085377d8db0b0e3cccac63"}}, "u": {"$push": {"dBRefForLocEntity": {"$ref": 
"geolocation", "$id": {"$oid": "630dbf36b2d3b5194196f4bd"}}}}}]}' with request id 
1059 to database productDB on connection [connectionId{localValue:8, serverValue:47}] 
to server mongo1:27021
2022-08-30 13:11:42 [http-nio-8080-exec-38] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command 
-Sending command '{"update": "orgEntity", "ordered": true, "writeConcern": {"w": 3, 
"j": true}, "txnNumber": 27, "$db": "productDB", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": 
{"$timestamp": {"t": 1661845302, "i": 38}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": 
{"base64": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 0}}, "lsid": 
{"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "bpl+TemyRby34zFE5DQheQ==", "subType": "04"}}}, 
"updates": [{"q": {"_id": {"$oid": "63085377d8db0b0e3cccac63"}}, "u": {"$push": 
{"dBRefForLocEntity": {"$ref": "geolocation", "$id": {"$oid": 
"630dbf36b2d3b5194197025a"}}}}}]}' with request id 1144 to database productDB on 
connection [connectionId{localValue:10, serverValue:48}] to server mongo1:27021
2022-08-30 13:11:43 [http-nio-8080-exec-39] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command 
-Sending command '{"update": "orgEntity", "ordered": true, "writeConcern": {"w": 3, 
"j": true}, "txnNumber": 34, "$db": "productDB", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": 
{"$timestamp": {"t": 1661845303, "i": 2}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": 
{"base64": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 0}}, "lsid": 
{"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "bpl+TemyRby34zFE5DQheQ==", "subType": "04"}}}, 
"updates": [{"q": {"_id": {"$oid": "63085377d8db0b0e3cccac63"}}, "u": {"$push": 
{"dBRefForLocEntity": {"$ref": "geolocation", "$id": {"$oid": 
"630dbf37b2d3b51941970ff8"}}}}}]}' with request id 1208 to database productDB on 
connection [connectionId{localValue:10, serverValue:48}] to server mongo1:27021
2022-08-30 13:11:43 [http-nio-8080-exec-41] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command 
-Sending command '{"update": "orgEntity", "ordered": true, "writeConcern": {"w": 3, 
"j": true}, "txnNumber": 54, "$db": "productDB", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": 
{"$timestamp": {"t": 1661845303, "i": 11}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": 
{"base64": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 0}}, "lsid": 
{"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "brfjBuGQSoeu5VwXGQMo1Q==", "subType": "04"}}}, 
"updates": [{"q": {"_id": {"$oid": "63085377d8db0b0e3cccac63"}}, "u": {"$push": 
{"dBRefForLocEntity": {"$ref": "geolocation", "$id": {"$oid": 
"630dbf37b2d3b51941971d95"}}}}}]}' with request id 1286 to database productDB on 
connection [connectionId{localValue:8, serverValue:47}] to server mongo1:27021
2022-08-30 13:11:43 [http-nio-8080-exec-37] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command 
-Sending command '{"update": "orgEntity", "ordered": true, "writeConcern": {"w": 3, 
"j": true}, "txnNumber": 72, "$db": "productDB", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": 
{"$timestamp": {"t": 1661845303, "i": 21}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": 
{"base64": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 0}}, "lsid": 
{"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "qAABBCCDDEEFFSSAAEE/AAD7A==", "subType": "04"}}}, 
"updates": [{"q": {"_id": {"$oid": "63085377d8db0b0e3cccac63"}}, "u": {"$push": 
{"dBRefForLocEntity": {"$ref": "geolocation", "$id": {"$oid": 
"630dbf37b2d3b51941972b33"}}}}}]}' with request id 1367 to database productDB on 
connection [connectionId{localValue:10, serverValue:48}] to server mongo1:27021*
```

The op-log shows the following operation for one of the $push items.

```
"o": {
    "$v": 1,
    "$set": {
      "dBRefForLocEntity.3468": {
        "$ref": "geolocation",
        "$id": {
          "$oid": "630db2b16c6f5e01638234a6"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From the update-log generated from oplog by running below commands can see that there are multiple overwrites to the same index.

```bash
mongodump -d local -c oplog.rs -o oplogD --port 27021
cd oplogD/local/
bsondump oplog.rs.bson  | jq . > updatelog.json

cat updatelog.json | grep  "dBRefForLocEntity.3468" 
          "dBRefForLocEntity.3468": {
          "dBRefForLocEntity.3468": {
          "dBRefForLocEntity.3468": {
          "dBRefForLocEntity.3468": {
          "dBRefForLocEntity.3468": {
          "dBRefForLocEntity.3468": {
          "dBRefForLocEntity.3468": {
          "dBRefForLocEntity.3468": {
```

This issue is not seen initially. After the list size grows to some 1500+ entries the issue happens consistently.

I tried all options from the code perspective (tried out all APIs provided by mongocollection/repository/$push/$addtoSet etc, also writing with WriteConcern.W3) but always hitting this issue.

Please provide your inputs to debug/rootcause this issue which is causing the overwrites to the list and/or any workarounds.

Comment: Perhaps the oplog entry shows the `"$push"` by `"$set"`ing a specific array location.  If you are losing data, I'd continue searching for the cuase.